# What is the meaning of given quote - When hungry, eat your rice; when tired, close your eyes

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, quotations

I wonder what is the meaning of this quote, It seems nothing is there. Or I am not understading. Thank you

> When hungry, eat your rice; when tired, close your eyes. Fools may
>   laugh at me, but wise men will know what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lifehacker](https://lifehacker.com/four-confusing-zen-quotes-and-what-you-can-learn-from-1676177538) sums it up beautifully:

> "Indeed, this saying does seem comical, but its simplicity is powerful. In our day to day lives we find a way to complicate everything. The food we eat, the work we do, the way we talk, the way we walk; everything has to "mean" something. Life would be much easier if you just responded to things appropriately. If you're hungry, eat something. If you're tired, get some rest. If you have work to complete, do your work. Stop wondering why you're hungry, why you're tired, or what the best way to do your work is and take a page out of Nike's book. Just do it. It's possible that your life could be much simpler than you make it out to be."

Comment: This is a good explanation, but I'm struggling to see any way in which it helps explain *English*. The same explanation could be given in and for any other language, it seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

just stop wondering about the reason to your problems and try to find solutions to them